# Using UIAlertView in swift for iOS 7.1+

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, uialertview

I have some code that works on iOS 8 but not on iOS 7.1 I am unsure what the code needs to look like for iOS 7.1

here's what I currently have that doesn't work on iOS 7.1

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "no connection", message: "dude, connect to the internet!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert!.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok!", style: .Cancel, handler: { (ac: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                    alert?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }))
self.presentViewController(alert!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

here's what I have tried to get UIAlertView to work on iOS 7.1+

```
let alert = UIAlertView() 
alert.title = "no connection"
alert.message = "dude, connect to the internet!"
alert.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want `UIAlertView` to have a nice completion handler. I do not care for the delegate pattern when using them, so I have come up with my own extension:

## UIAlertView Extension (Completion Handler)

```
// Used by objc_getAssociatedObject
private var UIAlertViewWrapperPropertyKey : UInt8 = 0

typealias AlertViewCompletionHandler = (alertView: UIAlertView, buttonIndex: Int) -> Void

extension UIAlertView
{
    // MARK: - Associated Properties

    private var wrapper : UIAlertViewWrapper?
    {
        get { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIAlertViewWrapperPropertyKey) as? UIAlertViewWrapper }
        set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIAlertViewWrapperPropertyKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)) }
    }

    // MARK - Convenience Initializers

    convenience init(title: String?, message: String?, cancelButtonTitle: String?)
    {
        self.init(title: title, message: message, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: cancelButtonTitle)
    }

    convenience init(title: String?, message: String?, cancelButtonTitle: String?, otherButtonTitles: String...)
    {
        self.init(title: title, message: message, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: cancelButtonTitle)

        for buttonTitle in otherButtonTitles { self.addButtonWithTitle(buttonTitle) }
    }

    // MARK: - Show with Completion Handler

    func showWithCompletion(_ completionHandler: AlertViewCompletionHandler? = nil)
    {
        self.wrapper = UIAlertViewWrapper(completionHandler: completionHandler)
        self.delegate = self.wrapper

        self.show()
    }

    // MARK: - Show Class Methods

    class func showWithTitle(title: String?, message: String?, cancelButtonTitle: String?, completionHandler: AlertViewCompletionHandler? = nil)
    {
        showWithTitle(title, message: message, cancelButtonTitle: cancelButtonTitle, otherButtonTitles: nil, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    class func showWithTitle(title: String?, message: String?, cancelButtonTitle: String?, otherButtonTitle: String?, completionHandler: AlertViewCompletionHandler? = nil)
    {
        let otherButtonTitles : [String]? = otherButtonTitle != nil ? [otherButtonTitle!] : nil

        showWithTitle(title, message: message, cancelButtonTitle: cancelButtonTitle, otherButtonTitles: otherButtonTitles, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    class func showWithTitle(title: String?, message: String?, cancelButtonTitle: String?, otherButtonTitles: [String]?, completionHandler: AlertViewCompletionHandler? = nil)
    {
        let alertView = UIAlertView(title: title, message: message, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: cancelButtonTitle)

        if let otherButtonTitles = otherButtonTitles
        {
            for buttonTitle in otherButtonTitles
            {
                alertView.addButtonWithTitle(buttonTitle)
            }
        }

        alertView.showWithCompletion(completionHandler)
    }
}
```

## UIAlertViewWrapper (Private Class)

```
// Private class that handles delegation and completion handler (do not instantiate)
private final class UIAlertViewWrapper : NSObject, UIAlertViewDelegate
{
    // MARK: - Completion Handlers

    var completionHandler: AlertViewCompletionHandler?

    // MARK: - Initializers

    init(completionHandler: AlertViewCompletionHandler?)
    {
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
    }

    // MARK: - UIAlertView Delegate

    private func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
    {
        completionHandler?(alertView: alertView, buttonIndex: buttonIndex)
    }
}
```

## Example Usage

```
// You can use class function to call the UIAlertView
UIAlertView.showWithTitle("Hello", message: "Hello World", cancelButtonTitle: "Okay") { alertView, buttonIndex in

    // Do something when the alert view is clicked
}

// Or... you can instantiate one and use the showWithCompletion method

let yesNoMaybeAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Choice", message: "Pick one", cancelButtonTitle: "No", otherButtonTitles: "Yes", "Maybe")

yesNoMaybeAlertView.showWithCompletion { alertView, buttonIndex in

    switch buttonIndex
    {
    case 1: println("Yes")
    case 2: println("Maybe")
    default: println("No")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UIAlertController is only available in ios8 or later per the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/). You will need to use a UIAlertView in ios7.

*Update*

Sorry I didn't fully understand what you were asking.

To build the UI simply do the following

```
let alert = UIAlertView(title: "no connection", message: "dude, connect to the internet!", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok!") 

alert.show()
```

And then make sure that you implementing [UIAlertViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/) in your VC. The above should dismiss the alert automatically but if not you can implement

```
alertView(_ alertView: UIAlertView,clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
```

and dismiss the alert from there

Comment: I know but I don't know how to port my code over to UIAlertView

Comment: you use UIAlertView for the view. UIAlertViewDelegate to handle the actions (func alertView(_ alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int))